# Does the alternating current "move" such that there can be Lorentz force present on the wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

As in question, does the alternating current "move" such that there can be Lorentz force present the wire? Becuase the current alternates on a fixed place there can be no Lorentz force?

Comment: I would not really think of it as the "current moving," rather the charges drift resulting in a current.  There is always a force on a current if $\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B} \neq 0$ (well, at least a component of the force... other terms can cancel this one resulting in a zero net force that's just complicating things).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily observer the Lorentz force produced by an alternating current by taking a reasonably strong magnet and holding it near a cord carrying a substantial current, for example for an electric kettle.  The cord is comprised of  two wires with currents flowing in opposite directions resulting in Lorentz forces in opposite directions on each wire.  Move the magnet around a bit and you can find and orientation so that the two forces will produce torques in the same direction.  As the current alternates the torque reverses.  You will feel the cord vibrate with a 50 Hz or 60 Hz frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Your concepts of AC needs to be revised. The Alternating Current is nothing but DC which changes with magnitude and direction with respect to time.

[image: AC supply]

In the above diagram the AC from 0 to T/2 is in forward direction( let's say) this is a matter of fact DC but changing magnitude with time. So if we apply calculus instantaneous Dc will have lorentz force in forward direction.

Similarly in T/2 to T interval the current will change direction to backward, and this time the Lorentz force will be in backward direction changing with magnitude praportional to current with respect to time.
The lorentz force will be there which will be alternating but will not become zero as you presumed.